# Obtener variable de un servicio en angular

Tags: angular

estoy desarrollando un servicio el cual integra el social login para logearse con una cuenta de google, al iniciarse el servicio, este verifica si ya se ha iniciado sesion para así almacenar un valor booleano(loggedIn) y la data(user) del usuario en unas variables del mismo servicio.

Mi pregunta es:

1)validar la variable loggedIn del servicio dentro del componente, aunque no se si sea mala practica. por el momento estoy validandola directamente en el html

2) como puedo mostrar la informacion del usuario en el componente

**codigo del servicio:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'

import { AuthService, GoogleLoginProvider, SocialUser } from 'angularx-social-login';


@Injectable()
export class UsuarioService {

    //variables que quiero usar y validar en los demas componentes

    user: SocialUser;
    loggedIn: boolean;

    constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
        console.log('Servicio de usuario iniciado')
        this.authService.authState.subscribe((user) => {
            this.user = user;
            this.loggedIn = (user != null);
            console.log(this.user)
        });
    }

    testService() {
        return ['Funciona', 'OK'];
    }


//metodo que pretende devolver el usuario, pero no funciona me devuelve undefined
  getUser(){
        return this.user
    }

    loginWhitGoogle() {
        this.authService.signIn(GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID);
    }
    signOut() {
        this.authService.signOut();
    }

}
```

**Codigo del componente**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthService, GoogleLoginProvider, SocialUser } from 'angularx-social-login';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';

//importar servio usario
import { UsuarioService } from '../../shared/services/usuario.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  signinForm: FormGroup;
user: SocialUser;


  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private authService: AuthService, private router: Router, private _userService: UsuarioService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.signinForm = this.fb.group({
      email: ['', Validators.required],
      password: ['', Validators.required]
    });


//aqui pretendo almacenar el usuario del servicio dentro de la varible user para usarla en el html, pero no funciona


 this.user = this._userService.getUser()
    console.log(this.user)
  }


  signInWithGoogle(): void {
    this._userService.loginWhitGoogle();
  }

  signOut(): void {
    this._userService.signOut();
  }
}
```

**Codigo del HTML**

```
  <!-- Aqui uso la variable loggedIn directamente desde el servicio, esto si funciona pero no se si sea mala practica-->
<div *ngIf="this._userService.loggedIn===false">
  <span><button type="button" (click)="signInWithGoogle()" class="btn btn-primary">Ingresa con tu correo
      institucional</button></span>
</div>

<!-- Esto funciona directamente desde el servicio  -->
<div>
  <p>Usuario desde servicio :</p> {{this._userService.user.name}}
</div>

<!-- Aqui no me muestra nada, desde el componente, lo que quiero es almancenar primero en una variable del componente para poder manipular la inforacion y validar y luego si mostrarla en el html -->
<div>
  <p>Usuario desde componente :</p> {{user.name}}
</div>
```

Luego de todo esto me surge una duda, es buena practica manipular la info en el servicio y mostrarla sirectamente en el HMTL?
O es mejor obtener la info desde el servicio y tratarla desde el componente para luego mostrarla en el HTML, de ser asi, es en este punto donde tengo incovenientes.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Por favor, coloca tu codigo y no imagenes para poder ayudarte con mejor claridad.

Comment: Alguien que sepa de angular no le va a ver problema, a mi parecer esta todo bien explicado y no veo la necesidad de poner un montón de código

Comment: Si necesitas ayuda entonces te recomiendo leas [Como Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)